# Landscape's OpenStack Autopilot: Launch instance getting network error

Tags: networking, juju, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I need some help in troubleshooting the network portion of my openstack setup. I have installed the landscape installer successfully. Every time I try to spin up a new instance I get this error. https://sites.google.com/site/openstackinthebasement3/errors/net_error.JPG?attredirects=0

I have tried the fix listed here, https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/57342/spawning-new-instances-fails-to-allocate-the-network/?answer=57370#post-id-57370 in the nova.conf file, but in my install juju manages this file and the changes get wiped out.

How can I troubleshoot this via JUJU? Is there an easy way to monitor/troubleshoot the networking portion of my install?

**Update:** I was able to add the nova.conf file options from the JUJU gui, but it didn't resolve the network errors that I am having.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed the cloud and applied this fix on nova compute node charm in the config-flag box vif_plugging_is_fatal=false,vif_plugging_timeout=0. After the restarted DHCP, things appear to be working error free.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you still have this issue but maybe for others.
I had to configure the parameter "network-manager (string)" in my nova-cloud-controller charm. You have to set the right network manager. In my case the following string: Neutron|Quantum

Comment: Thanks for the reply, mine is set by default to Neutron.